# c++ my program cannot initialize a handle on a process

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to edit memory in a program. For the most part the code works, but when I try to initiate a handle on the process, it returns `NULL`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int playerTotalRam = 761;

    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "generic game"); // specifies the window to act 
upon
    // error message if the window isn't found
    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        cout << "window not found!\n";
        system("PAUSE");
    } else {
        DWORD processID;                                                   
// stores the process id of the window
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processID);                        
// gets the process id of the window
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID); 
// opens the process with full access
        if (!handle) {
            cout << "couldnt initiate a handle on the process!\n";
            system("PAUSE");
        }

        // error message if the process ID isn't found
        if (processID == NULL) {
            cout << "cannot find process!\n";
            system("PAUSE");
        } else {
            WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)0x044A52C8, &playerTotalRam, 
4, 0); // this writes the new value to the listed address
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs "couldnt initiate a handle on the process!"

I have this same error with other programs.

What i want to know is what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this.

My system is windows 10 home.

Comment: Use `GetLastError` to find out why `OpenProcess` fails. Most likely this is related to your process privileges.

Comment: `OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` Did you try running it as administrator ?

Comment: `for the most part the code works` - i wonder what _most part_ did you mean

Comment: `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is WAY too much privileges to ask for just to use `WriteProcessMemory()`. All it requires is `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` and `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION`. Don't ask for more privileges than you really need. `OpenProcess()` may still fail if your app simply does not have permission to access the other process's memory.

Answer (score 0):

Either FindWindowA is failing, resulting in an incorrect process id because you have the wrong window title text or you're not running your program as administrator.  You need to run as administrator to get PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS permissions and make sure your title text is correct.  This will solve your problem.